# Extraer una fecha de un string en Java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de extraer la fecha de un string que puede venir en diferentes formatos como por ejemplo:

```
Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 14/10/2015
```

E incluso cosas después de la fecha, como por ejemplo:

```
Fecha 2015-11-24 asddsa12 Otros datos: 12202
```

Como podría hacer para extraer el `14/10/2015` de este String?

¿No hay una expresión regular que me permita tomar todo lo que está despues de "Fecha"? O algún otro tipo de solución.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Si buscas una solución con expresiones regulares, usa `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}` o `\d+\/\d+\/\d+`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario Jose! Ahí publiqué mas abajo como lo logré solucionar. Y si! Usé expresiones regulares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahi logré solucionarlo sin librerías externas:

```
private static boolean obtenerFecha(String palabra) {
    // Se fija si hace match con algun formato de fecha conocido
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{4}(/|-|.)[0-9]{2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{2})").matcher(palabra);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Encontrada la fecha!! --> " + m.group(0) + "\n");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Simplemente obtiene todos las coincidencias `matcher()` y los retorna con el `group()`

Answer (score 3):

```
String texto = "Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 14/10/2015";
//split crea una lista de elementos separados por la palabra "Fecha"
String[] texto_split = texto.split("Fecha"); 
// se elige el segmento 1 y se hace trim para quitar el espacio
String fecha = texto_split[1].trim();
```

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que en el segundo ejemplo que doy no funcionaría ya que me quedaría "2015-11-24 asddsa12 Otros datos: 12202"

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función **[`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))**. Esta función lo que haría sería crear un array tomando como referencia la palabra que le indiques.

Para tu ejemplo podrías usar:

```
String string = "Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 14/10/2015";
/* Divide tu string en partes tomando como referencia el string " Fecha " y lo almacena 
en un array */
String[] stringArray = string.split(" Fecha ");

System.out.println(stringArray[1]); //Devolverá 14/10/2015
```

Comment: El tema está en que quizás tengo cosas después de la fecha

Comment: @Genarito Entonces deberías de especificarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Ahí lo edité! Gracias

Comment: @Genarito ¿Siempre tendrá la misma estructura, es decir, no puede haber nada más después de la fecha que el texto `Otros datos`?

Comment: Ahí dice en la pregunta que puede venir en diferentes formatos

Comment: @Genarito Pensaba que te referías a diferentes formatos de fechas. Me refiero, puede venir sin nada detrás o solamente con Otros datos verdad?

Comment: Ahh sisi, puede venir con cualquier palabra antes o despues de "Fecha xx/xx/xxxx". Ahí modifiqué la pregunta para que quede mas claro! Gracias por el detalle!

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esto puedes usar la librería natty:
http://natty.joestelmach.com/

Que funcionaría para los 2 casos:

caso a)

```
import com.joestelmach.natty.*;

List<Date> dates = new Parser().parse("Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 12/10/2015").get(0).getDates();
System.out.println("Fecha: " + dates.get(0));
```

caso b)

```
List<Date> dates = new Parser().parse("Fecha 2015-11-24 asddsa12 Otros datos: 12202").get(0).getDates();
System.out.println("Fecha: " + dates.get(0));
```

Incluso para buscar varias fechas en la misma cadena:

```
List<Date> dates = new Parser().parse("Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 12/10/2015 Fecha 2015-11-24 asddsa12 Otros datos: 12202").get(0).getDates();
System.out.println("Fecha1: " + dates.get(0));
System.out.println("Fecha2: " + dates.get(1));
```

---

Otra opción es como comentan los compañeros mediante split().

```
String texto = "Cod. principal: 785369-06 Fecha 14/10/2015";
String[] array_split = texto.split("Fecha"); 
String myFecha = array_split[1].trim();
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero tuve problemas para importarlo sin Maven y en el Try it Out no funcionó en el caso de dd/mm/yyyy: se rompe con numeros mayores de 12 porque toma siempre los primeros dos números como mes y me descarta los mayores, por lo que tampoco me permite manipularlo como yo quiero ya que me los deja fuera de la instancia