# Como obtener todo lo que esta después de un carácter en un string

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una duda, es posible obtener todo lo que esta después de un caracter en un string?

Ejemplo:

Tengo este String

```
String ruta1 = api.getFileSystem().getFullPath(node);
                    tHeader.setText(ruta1);
```

El cual me devuelve una ruta ejemplo:

```
Archivos/Local/Carpeta/Valores
```

Y luego con `tHeader.setText(ruta1);` este muestra la ubicación donde te encuentras, sin embargo me muestra la ruta completa. ¿Es posible **solo** mostrar toda la ultima cadena de texto después del **/**? En este caso solo mostrar **"Valores"**

**Nota:** la variable ruta1 no siempre devolverá  `Archivos/local/carpeta/valores` eso es depende de donde el usuario se esté dirigiendo en la app, Puede ser:

```
Archivos/papeles/otras cosas/Empresa 1 
Universidad/Examenes/Primaria/1/Biologia 3
Otros archivos/papelera/PDF/Programacion/Java en android
```

Siempre estarán separados por **/** pero en este caso solo deseo que se pueda visualizar la **ultima** cadena después del **/** que serían:

```
Valores
Empresa 1
Biología 3
Java en android
```

Intente con esta pregunta similar: [Extraer una fecha de un string en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42462/extraer-una-fecha-de-un-string-en-java)

Sin embargo no entiendo como aplicar el código en mi caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la lógica que planteabas en tu pregunta existen varias vias para darle solución a tu problema

1. Separar tu ruta por los delimitadores en un arreglo y obtener el último elemento que es el que deseas.
2. Extraer la subcadena que quieres conociendo que es el texto que esta después del último caracter **/**

Teniendo estas dos opciones te lo voy a ejemplificar por separado.

**Primera:**

```
String ruta1 = api.getFileSystem().getFullPath(node);
//Separo la ruta en partes delimitadas por el caracter /
String[] parts = ruta1.split("/");
//Obtengo lo que quiero mostrar en el textview
String ultima = parts[parts.length-1];
tHeader.setText(ultima);
```

**Segunda:**

```
String ruta1 = api.getFileSystem().getFullPath(node);
//Obtengo lo que quiero mostrar en el textview (la subcadena)
String ultima = ruta1.substring(ruta1.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
tHeader.setText(ultima);
```

Comment: Me ha servido la solución **1**, pero cual es la diferencia con la segunda solución (la cual no me funciono)?

Comment: Intenta nuevamente con la segunda, que tenia la variable path y no existia y es ruta1. La diferencia es que la segunda es más óptima para lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: en realidad me fije en cambiar path por ruta1 y no dio frutos jajaja, bueno por lo menos me dio con la primera. Aunque tengo otro inconveniente, estoy tratando de agregar un search al action bar y no va. En el preview se ve el icono, pero al ejecutar la app no sale, he colocado el menu inflanter en el respectivo activity y nada, he cambiado de ifroom a always y tampoco, sale oculto con los tres puntos **...**

Comment: Intenta usar un searchwidget